# Twilio studio flow with whatsapp, how to receive media larger than 16MB (Error: 11751)

Tags: twilio, media, twilio-studio

I have a twilio flow associated with a WhatsApp conversation, and I am trying to receive a video using the "Send and wait for reply" widget

but if the video exceeds a maximum size of 16MB twilio studio does not receive any events

The question is how could I receive a video via WhatsApp larger than 16MB?

I tried to look for the error in the flow execution log, but no associated event was recorded.
I only get an error in the message logs as shown below
[Programmable Messaging Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHLAW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the current limitation of the file size for a WhatsApp message is 16MB. Please note that the size limit for images is only 5 MB.
[Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/guidance-whatsapp-media-messages#message-size-limits)